# Partial derivatives in thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, differentiation, equilibrium

In thermodynamics many definition has been made from partial derivatives at constant conditions for instance:

Let U be U:$f(S,V,m_k)$ then:

$$T = \left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial S} \right)_{V, m_{k}};  p = \left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial V} \right)_{S, m_{k}}; \mu_k = \left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial m_k} \right)_{V, S}$$

In a particular case, *heat of reaction and Van't Hoff relation*

Being H:$H(T,p, \xi)$

$$dH= \left( \frac{\partial H}{\partial T} \right)_{p, \xi}dT + \left( \frac{\partial H}{\partial p} \right)_{T, \xi}dp + \left( \frac{\partial H}{\partial \xi} \right)_{T, p}d\xi$$

Where $C_p$ is the specific heat at constant pressure, $h_T$ is the heat compressibility and $r_{T,p}$ is the heat of reaction at constant temperature and pressure:

$$C_p = \left( \frac{\partial H}{\partial T} \right)_{p, \xi} ; h_T = \left( \frac{\partial H}{\partial p} \right)_{T, \xi}; r_{T,p} = \left( \frac{\partial H}{\partial \xi} \right)_{T, p}$$

In terms of variation of affinity with temperature, the heat of reaction is given by (where $K$ is the equilibrium constant of a chemical reaction):

$$r_{T,p} = -RT^{2}\frac{\partial }{\partial T}ln K(T,p)$$

My question is : How can I define an equation where the left side needs constant temperature, but the right side implies the derivative of temperature?

Comment: I believe the equilibrium constant is a function of just the Temperature not Temperature and pressure as it says in your last equation

Comment: Taking derivative at constant temperature is not the same as saying that the said derivative does not depend on temperature. In your example, to calculate $r_{T,p}$ you take a derivative with respect to $\xi$. But $\xi$ itself might depend on other parameters, e.g., T and p. So, to emphasize that $\xi$ is used here as an independent variable one writes "derivative with respect to $\xi$ at constant T and p". However, since this derivative can be calculated at various values of T and p, the heat of reaction is generally dependent on both of them.

Comment: This is a math question, not a physics question.

Comment: @Riddler so youre saying that by stating $$ r_{T,p} = \left( \frac{\partial H}{\partial \xi} \right)_{T, p} $$ we are saying that $$d\xi$$ is independent of T and P but that the partial can be taken at multiple T and P. I do not understand how $$ r_{T,p} = -RT^{2}\frac{\partial }{\partial T}ln K(T,p) $$ is a function of T and P as K(the equilibrium constant) is only a function of T. Are you saying T is a function of p?

Comment: @Riddler But in case of temperature, Is it only measurable when volume is constant?  So for an expansion reaction there is not temperature to measure, Is it?

Comment: @ChemEng: The statement about the dependence of quantities on $T$ and $p$ is a mathematical one and comes from a simple fact that if there is a function $f(x, y, z)$, then any of its partial derivatives, say, $\partial f / \partial z$, generally depends on all variables, $x$, $y$, $z$. Of course, there could be physical constraints on the system (e.g., the equation of state) that would result in $\partial H(T,p,\xi) / \partial \xi$ having no dependence on $p$ but from the equations given in the question I see no such constraint. Do you have reasons to believe that $K$ is independent of $p$?

Comment: @JuanSebastianGarciaPerez: I am not sure I understand your question. Classical thermodynamics makes sense only in equilibrium. Even when there are non-stationary processes, such as chemical reactions, involved it is assumed that the system equilibrates quickly enough during the process. So, if you place a thermometer in your system you should get meaningful readings of $T$ *before* the state of the system changes appreciably. You would need to provide more information about the process you consider to get a clearer answer.

Comment: @ChemEng: I might try to guess what you had in mind. I am not a chemist but out of general physical considerations one can define the equilibrium constant, $K$, of a one-stage chemical reaction by the Arrhenius law, $K = A(T, p) \exp(-E_a / T)$, where $E_a$ is a constant. If you plug this into the expression for $r_{T,p}$ above, you get $r_{T,p} = R E_a$, which is a constant independent of both $T$ and $p$. However, I presume that in general, the expression for $K$ is more complicated and would lead to the full dependence on both variables.

Comment: @Riddler I believe the Arhenius equation is for the rate constant not the equilibrium constant. The rate constant is for chemical kinetics which tells you how fast a reaction happens and the equilibrium constant tells you the concentrations once the reaction reaches equilibrium. As far as i know the equilibrium constant is a function of Temperature not pressure

Comment: @ChemEng: You are right. I looked it up [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilibrium_constant). So, $K$ is actually the ratio of reaction rates. However, it seems to be also related to the change in the Gibbs free energy, $\Delta G$ (or enthalpy for constant $T$). And $\Delta G$ generally depends on $p$, for sure. But now I understand where your statement comes from: In practice the pressure dependence of $K$ is weak and hence neglected. But it is still there and you can find an example on the Wiki page.